# Using class name in print function

Tags: python

Newbie Pythonista here.

I am having a bit of an issue. I want to print a specific output which needs to be like **Point(x=1, y=2, z=3)** (xyz can of course be different in values).

This is the code:

```py
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Point(x={self.x}, y={self.y}, z={self.z})"
```

This is the test code:

```py
import unittest

from point import Point


class PointTests(unittest.TestCase):

    """Tests for Point."""

    def test_attributes(self):
        point = Point(1, 2, 3)
        self.assertEqual((point.x, point.y, point.z), (1, 2, 3))
        point.x = 4
        self.assertEqual(point.x, 4)

    def test_string_representation(self):
        point = Point(1, 2, 3)
        self.assertEqual(str(point), 'Point(x=1, y=2, z=3)')
        self.assertEqual(repr(point), 'Point(x=1, y=2, z=3)')
        point.y = 4
        self.assertEqual(str(point), 'Point(x=1, y=4, z=3)')
        self.assertEqual(repr(point), 'Point(x=1, y=4, z=3)')

    def test_equality_and_inequality(self):
        p1 = Point(1, 2, 3)
        p2 = Point(1, 2, 4)
        p3 = Point(1, 2, 3)
        self.assertNotEqual(Point(1, 2, 3), Point(1, 2, 4))
        self.assertEqual(Point(1, 2, 3), Point(1, 2, 3))
        self.assertFalse(Point(1, 2, 3) != Point(1, 2, 3))
        self.assertNotEqual(p1, p2)
        self.assertEqual(p1, p3)
        p3.x, p3.z = p3.z, p3.x
        self.assertNotEqual(p1, p3)
        self.assertTrue(p1 != p3)
        self.assertFalse(p1 == p3)
```

The problem I am having is that in **str** function when I am using a "**Point**" in the print format I am thrown with an assertion error:

> AssertionError: 'point.Point object at 0x7fbd8850b190' != 'Point(x=1, y=2, z=3)'

But when I use anything else it gets printed. For example lets say I use *points* instead of *Point*:

> 'points(x=1, y=2, z=3)' != 'Point(x=1, y=2, z=3)'

Why does that happen and how can I get around this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error occurrs at

```
self.assertEqual(repr(point), 'Point(x=1, y=2, z=3)')
```

Since you have customly defined only the `__str__` method on `__Point__`, `__repr__` is still the built-in-method, resulting in something like `"point.Point object at 0x7fbd8850b190"`. To fix this, define the `__repr__` of `Point`.

When you define the `__repr__` method, python uses it as a default for `__str__`, but it does not do the other way around.

With your (not so minimal) code example, this will still lead to an error at

```
self.assertEqual(Point(1, 2, 3), Point(1, 2, 3))
```

This is because this line does not test for equality of the representations, but for the equality of objects. Since you instantiate `Point` twice, the first argument of your `assertEqual` is actually different from the second argument, even if they are both instances of `Point` and even if they are equal with regard to their instance variables.

You can understand these objects as something like "twins" or "clones": even if all their attributes are the same, they still have a different "identity".

If we want to consider "twins" as "equal", Python allows us to define an equality relation used by Python to check for equality of objects. We can define this by implementing the `__eq__` method. Most probably you want something like:

```
class Point:
    def  __init__(x, y, z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Point(x={self.x}, y={self.y}, z={self.z})"

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.__repr__() == other.__repr__()
```

It might be a good idea to read an introduction into Python's "magic methods", such as https://rszalski.github.io/magicmethods/

Comment: It managed to fix the "0x7fbd8850b190" part but now when running I am getting: AssertionError: Point(x=1, y=2, z=3) != Point(x=1, y=2, z=3). How does that make sense?

Comment: If I understood from your comment, I replaced __str__ with __repr__ . 

This is the traceback:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 29, in test_equality_and_inequality
AssertionError: Point(x=1, y=2, z=3) != Point(x=1, y=2, z=3)

Comment: Thank you for your feedback and your help! It worked :D

Answer (score 1):

On my end with python 3, you have two failing tests.

```
======================================================================
FAIL: test_equality_and_inequality (test_point.PointTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/josef/tmp/deleteme/test_point.py", line 29, in test_equality_and_inequality
    self.assertEqual(Point(1, 2, 3), Point(1, 2, 3))
AssertionError: <point.Point object at 0x7f7a20cff050> != <point.Point object at 0x7f7a20cff090>
```

This one is happening because the return from declaring a new object is the object itself with its unique id. Evaluating `Point(1, 2, 3)` returns a unique thing like `<point.Point object at 0x7f7a20cff050>`, and not the class itself. So if you instantiate two instances of a class, they are necessarily different.

```
======================================================================
FAIL: test_string_representation (test_point.PointTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/josef/tmp/deleteme/test_point.py", line 19, in test_string_representation
    self.assertEqual(repr(point), 'Point(x=1, y=2, z=3)')
AssertionError: '<point.Point object at 0x7f7a20d75f90>' != 'Point(x=1, y=2, z=3)'
- <point.Point object at 0x7f7a20d75f90>
+ Point(x=1, y=2, z=3)
```

Python classes can have a `__str__` method and a `__repr__` method. The former is mostly used to return string representations of the object, so you have something that looks nice if you're displaying it to a human. The latter I see less used (I still usually define it anyhow) but is to my understanding supposed to enable a "object-to-representation-to-object" roundtrip; to display the instance in such a way that you could in theory just `eval()` that string representation and faithfully reproduce the object.

Your class definition doesn't have a `__repr__` so that test of course fails. Sometimes (for large values of sometimes) if I'm lazy I'll do this:

```py
def __str__(self):
    return self.__repr__()
```

Comment: This is not the way of doing, it.  You should implement `__repr__ ` and str will rely on it without needing to implement it

Comment: It fixed the weird 0xXXXXXXXX part but now I am getting AssertionError: Point(x=1, y=2, z=3) != Point(x=1, y=2, z=3). They are the same for as much as I know

Comment: That's because it's still comparing instance to instance I think, not textual representation to textual representation. :)